# Ordenar resultado de query en Fila ordenada

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta que obtengo con este query:

`Select Año, Tip, Est, t1, t2, t3 From Tabla1`

```
Año     Tip Est Zo  t1  t2  t3  

2003    1   A   6   12  14  17  
2003    1   A   7   12  15  18  
2003    1   A   8   13  16  19  
2003    1   A   9   10  12  14  
2003    1   A   10  12  14  17  
2004    1   A   1   11  13  15
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar el query para tener un resultado parecido a esto?

```
Año     Tip Est Zo  Ts 

2003    1   A   6   12
2003    1   A   6   14
2003    1   A   6   17
2003    1   A   7   12
2003    1   A   7   15
2003    1   A   7   18
2003    1   A   8   13
2003    1   A   8   16
2003    1   A   8   19
2003    1   A   9   10
2003    1   A   9   12
2003    1   A   9   14
```

Lo que se está haciendo es colocar las columnas t1, t2, t3 en fila con los mismos años a los que pertenecen.

**¿Cómo podría lograr eso?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server te permite hacer un [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), diseñado justamente para esta situación:

```
select año, tip, est, zo, ts
  from tabla1
unpivot (
  ts for columnas in (t1, t2, t3)
) as unpvt
 order by ... -- aquí le pones las columnas que necesitas para establecer el orden deseado
```

Otra opción interesante es la de usar [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select t.año, t.tip, t.est, t.zo, v.ts
  from tabla1 t
 cross apply (
   values (t.t1), (t.t2), (t.t3)
 ) as v(ts)
 order by ... -- aquí le pones las columnas que necesitas para establecer el orden deseado
```

En ambos casos, el rendimiento debería ser bueno ya que solo se necesita recorrer la tabla una vez.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono el UNPIVOT

Answer (score 3):

Si bien creo entender quieres agruparlo en una sola columna, puedes hacerlo con un `union all`

```
SELECT  *
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        Año, Tip, Est, Zo, t1
    FROM
        Tabla1) 
UNION ALL (SELECT 
        Año, Tip, Est, Zo, t2
    FROM
        Tabla1) 
UNION ALL (SELECT 
        Año, Tip, Est, Zo, t3
    FROM
        Tabla1)) tabla
ORDER BY Est;
```

Answer (score -2):

Debes agregar [`ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

Prueba la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT Año, Tip, Est, t1
FROM Tabla1
ORDER BY Zo
```